# Musixtex and two columns

Tags: multicol, musixtex

I love LaTeX. Unfortunatly some years passed since I last used it. Now I want to layout a leaflet with several songs and nodes. I found musixtex which seems to work awesome. The only thing I do not understand:

- How can I use two column mode (with multicols package) automatically so it breaks one musixtex line into two (or more) if it does not fit into one column?

As an example my script

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{musixtex}
\usepackage{multicol}
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}

\begin{music}
\generalsignature{1}
\startextract
\NOtes\zsong{Nun }\qu g\en
\NOtes\zsong{dan }\qu g\en
\NOtes\zsong{ket }\qu h\en
\NOtes\zsong{alle- }\qu h\en
\NOtes\zsong{alle- }\qu h\en
\NOtes\zsong{alle- }\qu h\en
\NOtes\zsong{alle- }\qu h\en
\NOtes\zsong{alle- }\qu h\en
\bar
\endextract
\end{music}

\begin{music}
\generalsignature{1}
\startextract
%\geometricskipscale
\NOtes\zsong{Nun }\qu g\en
\NOtes\zsong{dan }\qu g\en
\NOtes\zsong{ket }\qu h\en
\NOtes\zsong{alle- }\qu h\en
\NOtes\zsong{alle- }\qu h\en
\NOtes\zsong{alle- }\qu h\en
\NOtes\zsong{alle- }\qu h\en
\bar
\endextract
\end{music}

\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

My impression is that this measures are too "full". This is evident from a warning message while generating the `.mx2` file:

> This shouldn't happen ! Too few bars or \mulooseness too large ?

It looks fine in `twocolumn` mode which gives wider columns:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{multicol,lipsum,musixtex}
\begin{document}


\lipsum[1]

\begin{music}
\parindent0ex
\generalsignature{1}
%\hsize=\columnwidth
\startpiece%
\Notes\zsong{Nun}\qu g%
\zsong{dan}\qu g%
\zsong{ket}\qu h%
\zsong{alle-}\qu h%
\zsong{alle-}\qu h%
\zsong{alle-}\qu h%
\zsong{alle-}\qu h%
\zsong{alle-}\qu h\en%
\bar%
\Notes\zsong{Nun }\qu g%
\zsong{dan}\qu g%
\zsong{ket}\qu h%
\zsong{alle-}\qu h%
\zsong{alle-}\qu h%
\zsong{alle-}\qu h\en%
\mulooseness=1%
\Stoppiece%
\end{music}
\medskip


\lipsum[1-2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

You can also make it work with manual line breaks in narrow columns.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol,lipsum,musixtex}
\begin{document}


\begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{music}
\parindent0ex
\generalsignature{1}
%\hsize=\columnwidth
\startpiece%
\Notes\zsong{Nun}\qu g%
\zsong{dan}\qu g%
\zsong{ket}\qu h%
\zsong{alle-}\qu h%
\zsong{alle-}\qu h%
\zsong{alle-}\qu h
\en\zalaligne\Notes%
\zsong{alle-}\qu h%
\zsong{alle-}\qu h\en%
\bar%
\Notes\zsong{Nun }\qu g%
\zsong{dan}\qu g%
\zsong{ket}\qu h%
\en\zalaligne\Notes%
\zsong{alle-}\qu h%
\zsong{alle-}\qu h%
\zsong{alle-}\qu h\en%
%\mulooseness=1%
\Stoppiece%
\end{music}
\medskip


\lipsum[1-2]
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

[image]